# Good examples of unit test suites

Tags: unit-testing

For those of us who like to learn by reading good code, what are some of the projects you've seen which provide a great example of a medium to large suite of unit tests in action?

This isn't a question about what your favourite unit testing framework is, but it could be helpful to add which unit testing and/or mocking frameworks are used by the projects you mention.

Any platform will do, but I'm mainly interested in projects which use an *x*Unit-style unit testing framework in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) has a mind-numbingly large array of unit tests. They are written to Junit, and include the JUnit-Spring mechanisms as well as one of the mock libraries. They include launching processes and many other mechanisms you might need some day.

Answer (score 0):

For example, [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/ftp/) uses Python's `unittest` module (also known as [PyUnit](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/)) and has lots unit test that you might want to take a look at.

I'm also using `unittest` myself. It is very similar to Java's jUnit framework and thus very handy for writing tests in no time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Service Factory](http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/) has about 780 unit tests, including some that test code meant to run inside of Visual Studio. It has some very good examples of mocking such code.

The [Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) has even more.

Answer (score 0):

[NunitLite](https://launchpad.net/nunitlite) has a [unit tests suite](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~nunitlite-dev/nunitlite/trunk/files/head:/src/NUnitLiteTests/) but I'm not sure it qualifies as a medium-sized project. I seem to remember [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) also has unit tests, but its site currently is unavailable.